# Error while storing data from Hashmap to Array

Tags: java, arrays, error-handling

I'm trying to store some data from a HashMap to an Array. The hashmap is created from a JSON file and it looks like this (I'm inserting just a small part of the hashmap) :

```
2b6c784c=[3462C8, 2.88, -25.55, 29.0, 37000.0, 468.0, 3654, F-EST, A332, EC-NEN, 1.649452502E9, EZE, BCN, IB2602, 0.0, 0.0, IBE2602, 0.0, ], 2b6d6d1f=[448191, 50.9, 4.48, 78.0, 0.0, 19.0, 0000, T-EBBR141, GRND, , 1.649452503E9, , , , 1.0, 0.0, , 0.0, ]
```

I'm trying to store the first element of the given array into another array. For example I'm trying to insert the ***String*** values **3462C8, 448191** into an array called results. This is the code I have come up with:

```
public String[] Process() throws Exception {

        HashMap<String, ArrayList<Object>> data = gson.fromJson(JsonContent.toString(), HashMap.class);
        String[] results = new String[20];

        for(Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<Object>> entry : data.entrySet()){
             results[0] = String.valueOf(entry.getValue().get(0));

        }

        return  results;
    }
```

However whenever I run the code, a small part of it is being executed and at the end it gives me an error:

> **java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Double cannot be cast to class java.util.ArrayList (java.lang.Double and java.util.ArrayList are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')**

Is there any way I can solve this problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Enable all compiler warnings.  That will tell you why this is happening.  `gson.fromJson` will return a HashMap, but it is not guaranteed to be a `HashMap<String, ArrayList<Object>>`.  That assumption is the cause of your error.  The only safe assumption you can make is `HashMap<?, ?>`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think, that your error happens when you store data in array, as you mentioned in the question. An error occurs when you try to convert JSON into HashMap.